# LinkedArticle (knowledge) : query the linked articles of a case

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge

I need to query all the linked articles of a case, so I just try to use this kind of query in the query editor of the developer console :

```
select Id from LinkedArticle where LinkedEntityId = 'the id of my case here'
```

But it throws me an error saying :

> select Id from LinkedArticle where LinkedEntityId = '5009E000005yCEIQA2' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:36 No such column 'LinkedEntityId' on entity 'LinkedArticle'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

But [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_linkedarticle.htm) I can see that the field exist... But I checked the workbench and for the linkedArticle object there is no LinkedEntityId field !

So how can I specify the id of the case ? I don't want to retrieve all the linkedArtcile, just for one case at a time (I will use this query in an apex class).

(I use the api version 42.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the knowledge articles which are linked to a Case, you need to perform query on `CaseArticle` object as below

```
SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, ArticleLanguage, ArticleVersionNumber 
FROM CaseArticle 
WHERE CaseId= '5000v000002J6Sj'
```

[image: caseArticle]

For more information, refer [CaseArticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casearticle.htm)

`LinkedArticle` object represents Knowledge article that is attached to a work order or work order line item.

Comment: Ok, so when I query the CaseArticle object, then I can retrieve a list of KnowledgeArticleId and query the LinkedArticle that has the same KnowledgeArticleId !

Comment: Based on `KnowledgeArticleId` you need to query respected KnowledgeArticle object

Comment: Ok I retrive the KnowledgeArticle associated to the KnowledgeArticleId. Now how can I get the property of the article like the body, etc ? Is the KnowledgeArticle object linked to another object ?